# Linux Mint ignores Mouse Click / Focus cannot be transferred to another Window

Tags: window-manager, focus, cinnamon

Why am I apparently losing mouse focus if more than one window is open?
I am using Linux Mint 13 64bit (Cinamon).

---

**Examples** where Chromium apparently locks the focus:

- 1. I open up Chromium and play around a little bit
  2. then I try to open any programms from the taskbar
  3. I cannot click on them.

- 1. I open two Windows (e.g. Chromium and a Terminal)
  2. then I work with Chromium
  3. then I click into the Terminal
  4. the terminal get's no focus on it.

Comment: I found out, if i click ont the window's title bar (from the Programm, not System-one), Focus set free and I can Navigate to another Windows.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the Main Reasson for this Problem. The Problem only appears, if any Window has an activated TextBox. If I just click into an TextBox (dosnt matter if its a browser, a terminal or something else), this Window locks the Focus.

Comment: Are you using the compositor?  I had problems with this, and turned off the compositor.  With my situation though it was using XFCE and the some gnome tools.  Turn it off and I didn't have the problems.  But it did exhibit what you are describing, clicking 'through' the terminal body and accidentally clicking on links, etc.

Comment: I look around a bit and found out, that the Compositor was already off. Is it possible that the Problems come from the AMD Graphic Drivers?
My System runs on a Radeon HD 6800 with two Monitors via DVI.

Comment: I searched a bit around and found a Post at Unix exchange, who describes exact my Problem.
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/mouse-clicks-stop-working-after-random-time-using-awesome-wm-gnome

Comment: I am getting the exact same error with Gnome 3 for debian AND Ubuntu 14 on a PC I am trying to transition from Windows 7 to a linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

---

Linux version 3.13.0-37-generic (buildd@kapok) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19Ubuntu1) ) #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014)

AKA: Linux Mint 17.1, Rebecca, Cinnamon (64-bit)

The version you have installed is earlier than the release I am using, but the description of your problem is exactly one that I have been facing. The workaround described below works for me, and with a little bit of luck, may work on earlier releases...

---

I've been facing this issue too, yet have not found a fix for it, only a workaround.

I found that destroying (not closing) the application that has hold of the mouse operability, releases it's control over it. This is annoying when you're browser with 10+ tabs decides to lock the mouse...

The best work-around I found for it after some experimentation, is to use the 'Windows Special Key' to move the application in question around a little bit, and mouse /should/ be released. At least this has been working for me when it happens. Not ideal, but a quick alt-drag (my windows key is alt, you can set this in 'System Settings -> Windows -> Moving and Resizing Windows')

Best of luck!

Comment: This is an old question.  It isn't clear whether you had the same issue several years ago with Mint 13, whether you are currently installing Mint 13 and encountering the problem, or you are installing a current version of Mint and the problem has persisted across versions.  Can you edit your answer to clarify?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, my apologies -

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Ensure you don't have compositor on.

Comment: Compositor wasn't being used, per comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

The window manager is responsible for window selection and focus. Figure out which window manager you have running (X session) and consult their documentation on the topics of "window focus". Cinnamon seems to be a fork of GNOME 2.

For example: [Fluxbox: focus model](http://fluxbox.sourceforge.net/docbook/en/html/fluxbox-man.html#lbAK)

Answer (score 0):

The problem still exists. I'm using the latest Mint with the latest everything. It is related to the use of Mono. Installing Keepass2 "causes" the problem. I found that uninstaling Keepass2 then re-instaling it seems to fix the problem. I think it is to do with the order that mono gets installed with Keepass2 or post install triggers. When you do a normal uni-install of Keepass2 it leaves mono behind. I'm guessing re-inall of keepass does not install a 'new' mono.